# Sound effect to Object location/rotation synchronization

Tags: objects, audio

Currently using Blender 2.92

Is there a way to synch or assign a sound effect every time an object matches a specific location/rotation criteria?

I'm working on a set of 12 pendulums, oscillating at different speed, and I would like to assign to each pendulum a different note (12 pendulums, 12 notes, 1 full octave) that would be heard every time each particular pendulum passes through zero rotation (straight down).

Thanks in advance for the help/tips/hints ~ Cheers

Comment: Have done this using speakers and the NLA. _eg_ if a speaker has  a 2 second "dong" ,starting at frame 1, run a script to add a copy of  speaker at location of hit, and  frame of hit via NLA. (and hide them when not playing.)

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks - a bit out of my comfort range then. But that's OK. I should have stated in my original post that I'm far from being a pro. Haven't reached the script part yet, nor have I touched the NLA. Will need to look into both of these. Any pointers you could think of so that I don't follow the wrong path on these?